Unable to understand for...in in JavaScript objects
I have below spaceship object in JavaScript and then nested objects as well.
js


let spaceship = {
  crew: {
    captain: {
      name: 'Lily'
    },
    'chief officer': {
      name: 'Dan',
    },
    medic: {
      name: 'Clementine',
    },
    translator: {
      name: 'Shauna',
    }
  }
};

for (let crewMember in spaceship.crew) {
  console.log(`${crewMember}:${crewMember.name}`)
}



I am trying to use for...in loop but:
displays output as:
captain:undefined
chief officer:undefined
medic:undefined
translator:undefined

Whereas I expect:
captain:Lily
chief Dan
medic:Clementine
translator:Shauna

To achieve the above result, I can do this instead
console.log(`${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name}`)

But I am unable to understand why I can't achieve the same using former code, i.e.
console.log(`${crewMember}:${crewMember.name}`)


If the variable crewMember holds the string 'captain', why would you expect 'captain'.name to work…?

You're saying you don't understand why map[key].property is not the same as key.property?

This is what you actually looking for? console.log(${crewMember}: ${spaceship.crew[crewMember].name});

You've mistaken the value and key
Better naming will help:


let spaceship = {
  crew: {
    captain: {
      name: 'Lily'
    },
    'chief officer': {
      name: 'Dan',
    },
    medic: {
      name: 'Clementine',
    },
    translator: {
      name: 'Shauna',
    }
  }
};

for (let crewMemberKey in spaceship.crew) {
  const crewMember = spaceship.crew[crewMemberKey]
  console.log(`${crewMemberKey}:${crewMember.name}`)
}



